# Receiving Application defined error for this folmula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am getting application-defined error 1004 for the formula where I am trying to find the cells with only public email ids such as gmail yahoo etc. I replaced @ with # previously.

```
Dim n As String
n = vbNullString
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2," & "#" & "," & n & "))=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(G2," & "#gmail.com" & "," & "^" & ")," & "#yahoo.com" & "," & "^" & ")," & "#yahoo.co.in" & "," & "^" & ")," & "#rediffmail.com" & "," & "^" & ")," & "#hotmail.com" & "," & "^" & "))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(G2," & "#gmail.com" & "," & "^" & ")," & "#yahoo.com" & "," & "^" & ")," & "#yahoo.co.in" & "," & "^" & ")," & "#rediffmail.com" & "," & "^" & ")," & "#hotmail.com" & "," & "^" & ")," & "^" & "," & "))," & "All Public recipients" & "," & "OK" & ")"
```

Comment: If you had to manually put the formula in a cell. How would it look like?

Comment: you to add triple Quotation marks to your strings like this `"""#gmail.com"""`, so they get passed to Excel as strings with single Quotation marks.

Comment: Other question, what's your goal with `vbNullString`? For example `SUBSTITUTE(G2,""#"",)` gives you the exact same result.